# Adding package from local repo fails

Tags: swift, swift-package-manager

While this use to work, it seems that adding a Swift Package from a local repo (not online, but a bare repo from a file path) fails.

The file path must start with `file:///path/to/libRip.git`. That works.

Pressing 'Add Package', shows an error: *"Fail to resolve dependencies"*.

Trying the 'Add Local' button: *"Cannot select this directory, it does not contain a Package.swift file."*. I'm selecting again, the repo, not the code base.
So, by 'Add Local', this means the actual project? Not a repo?

Uploading the same lib project to GitHub works.

Package file looks like this:

```
let package = Package(
    name: "MyLib",
    platforms: [.iOS(.v12), .macOS(.v10_12)],
    products: [
        .library(
            name: "MyLib",
            targets: ["MyLib"]),
    ],
    targets: [
        .target(
            name: "MyLib",
            dependencies: []),
        .testTarget(
            name: "MyLibTests",
            dependencies: ["MyLib"]),
    ]
)
```

Why does it matter where the repo is hosted? If it's on a server or a location on my machine?

Answer (score 0):

Compiler-error `no such module...` appeared after Xcode 13.4.1 upgrade in a project that used to work before and did not change. This caused me to try to remove and add a local package again.

There I faced your error `Cannot select this directory, it does not contain a Package.swift file.`  But, I added the local package from folder (by Menu -> File -> "Add packages..."  not from File -> URL.

Finally it helped to create a new local package from scratch and add the sources of the old package therein. Using the new package, the error did not occur.

By the way, I faced other problems when trying to add the local package from a mounted device (DMG). Moving the package to Macintosh HD solved the problem.